# Altair LOESS fit below avg values, far below linear regresion

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I'm relatively new to Altair, and have run into an issue that I can't seem to understand. Basically when I'm fitting a LOESS fit to my data, the entire LOESS line is being drawn below the sample average, below averages at each time point, and below my regression fit.

The data is a panel with monthly arrest rate (part 2 crimes per 1,000 people) for number of localities.

Here's a plot with monthly average rates, a linear regression fit, and my loess. As you can see, the loess is way below all the data:

[image]

The code for this is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()

# Load panel data. Monthly arrest rate (part 2 crimes per 1,000 people)
# data for number of localities.

panel = pd.read_csv(
    "https://github.com/nickeubank/im_baffled/raw/main/arrest_rates.csv.zip"
)

# And if I do averages for each month, I get
# a relatively smooth downward trend.

grouped_means = panel.groupby("years_w_decimals", as_index=False)[
    ["arrest_rate"]
].mean()

chart_grouped = (
    alt.Chart(grouped_means)
    .mark_circle(opacity=0.5)
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("years_w_decimals", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
        y=alt.Y("arrest_rate", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
)

reg = (
    alt.Chart(panel)
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("years_w_decimals", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
        y=alt.Y("arrest_rate", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
    .transform_regression(
        "years_w_decimals",
        "arrest_rate",
        method="poly",
        order=1,
    )
    .mark_line()
)

loess = (
    alt.Chart(panel)
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("years_w_decimals", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
        y=alt.Y("arrest_rate", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
    .transform_loess(on="years_w_decimals", loess="arrest_rate", bandwidth=0.3)
    .mark_line()
)
reg + chart_grouped + loess
```

Any chance anyone can see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after much investigation, the issue is that, as @joelostblom suggested, related out outliers.

More specifically, looks like Vega is using a less-traditional LOESS implementation (without a lot of documentation :/): https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7686

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what is happening is that you have some points with extreme y-values that affect one of the regression computations more than the other and when you zoom in the plot on just the grouped averaged, it looks like a bigger difference than what it is if you saw the full range of the plots with all those extreme points.

```
panel2= panel.sample(200, random_state=200)
chart_grouped = (
    alt.Chart(panel2)
    .mark_circle(opacity=0.5)
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("years_w_decimals", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
        y=alt.Y("arrest_rate", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
)

reg = (
    alt.Chart(panel2)
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("years_w_decimals", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
        y=alt.Y("arrest_rate", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
    .transform_regression(
        "years_w_decimals",
        "arrest_rate",
    )
    .mark_line()
)

loess = (
    alt.Chart(panel2)
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("years_w_decimals", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
        y=alt.Y("arrest_rate", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
    .transform_loess(
        "years_w_decimals",
        "arrest_rate",
    )
    .mark_line()
)
loess + reg
```

[image]

That looks pretty bad, but plotting the full range with original points makes it look more reasonable.

[image]

Maybe the most appropriate here is to run the two regressions on the points your are showing in the scatter plot, this is what it looks like for the grouped points:

```
chart_grouped = (
    alt.Chart(grouped_means)
    .mark_circle(opacity=0.5)
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("years_w_decimals", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
        y=alt.Y("arrest_rate", scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
    )
)
reg = chart_grouped.transform_regression(
        "years_w_decimals",
        "arrest_rate",
    ).mark_line()

loess = chart_grouped.transform_loess(
        "years_w_decimals",
        "arrest_rate",
    ).mark_line()

chart_grouped + loess + reg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @joelostblom! I think you might be right it's related to the outliers, and your workaround is obviously an excellent fix, but the fact that given your experience you don't see anything obviously wrong makes me think this is an implementation problem with loess, not a user error on my part, so I think I'll reported as a bug.